# Formalization of Lemma for proof of AM-GM inequality

Tags: logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, formal-grammar

The question is not about how to prove the lemma (I proved it by induction) but I wanted to understand the correct formalization of the lemma:

**Lemma used to prove AM-GM inequality:** If $ a_1,a_2,...,a_n  $ are real and positive numbers satisfying $ a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot ... \cdot a_n =1 $ then $ \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \geq n
 $.

**My attempts at formalization:**

1. $ \forall n \in {\bf{N}} \forall x_1 \in {\bf{R}} \forall x_2 \in {\bf{R}} ...\forall x_n \in {\bf{R}} ( ( x_1,x_2,...,x_n > 0 \land x_1 \cdot \cdot \cdot x_n = 1 ) \Rightarrow x_1 + ... + x_n \geq n )
    $
2. $ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\, \forall x_k\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}\,(k=1,\ldots,n)\, : \,\prod_{k=1}^nx_k =1\Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^nx_k\geq n $
3. $ (\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(\forall k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\})(\forall x_k\in \{r\in \mathbb{R}\, : \,r>0\})\, : \, \prod_{k=1}^nx_k =1\Longrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^nx_k\geq n $

**Are these formalizations correct?**

***Regarding (1):***  back when I proved the lemma I formalized it to (1) above, but I'm not sure if it is correct now logically ( after reading the following question :  [How to formalize $\text{span}(S)=\{c_1v_1+\cdots+c_kv_k\mid v_1,~\cdots,~v_k\in S,~c_1,~\cdots,~c_k\in F\}$ rigorously in first order language?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407797/how-to-formalize-textspans-c-1v-1-cdotsc-kv-k-mid-v-1-cdots-v-k-in)  ) since I have $ n $ quantifiers followed by the first quantifier ( $ \forall n \in \Bbb N  $ ) where it is written " $ \forall n \in {\bf{N}} \forall x_1 \in {\bf{R}} \forall x_2 \in {\bf{R}} ...\forall x_n \in {\bf{R}} $ "  ( and I think this is called 'not well-formed' in first-order logic )

***Regarding (2):*** looks little bit awkward for a beginner like me, but it means the same thing as (3) which seems clearer.

***Regarding (3):*** I'm not sure if it is a correct formalization, because in the induction step, where I assume the claim for $ n $ and prove it for $ n+1 $ then afterwards I'll also have to continue my proof like so: " Let $  k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n,n+1\}  $ be arbitrary . Let $ x_k \in \{r\in \mathbb{R}\, : \,r>0\}\,  $ be arbitrary " but then I'd stumble upon a difficulty when I'll have to assume $ \prod_{k=1}^{n+1} x_k =1$ since I've introduced only one arbitrary variable ( $ x_k  $ ) and not $ n+1 $ arbitrary variables.

If you have other formalization that is correct, can you please write it very rigorously and precisely? ( I would like to know better how to formalize correctly regarding theories that discuses $ n $ number of mathematical objects )

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Attempt (1) is perfectly fine, and the most standard among the three.
2. Attempt (2) is also fine, except that I would replace the colon (which normally is read “such that”, and in never necessary in the language of first-order logic) with a set of parentheses like in (1). Also, $\mathbb R^+$ is an
   alternative to $\mathbb R_{>0},$  and perhaps use different dummy
   variables $i$ and $k$ for the $\Pi$ and $\Sigma.$
3. In attempt (3), the declaration for $k$ feels pedantic. $\{r\in
   \mathbb{R}\, : \,r>0\}$ is simply $(0,\infty).$ The parentheses
   around each quantifier are unnecessary.

My own attempt: $$\forall n\in\mathbb N \;\;\forall a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R^+ \,\Bigl(a_1\ldots a_n =1\implies a_1+\ldots+a_n \geq n\Bigr)$$ or $$\forall n\in\mathbb N \;\;\forall a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R^+ \left(\prod_{j=1}^n a_j =1\implies \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \geq n\right).$$

P.S. Note that the parentheses are required here: the convention (*quantifiers apply to as little as is construeable*) is to read $$\forall n\in\mathbb N \;\;\forall a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R^+ \prod_{j=1}^n a_j =1\implies \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \geq n$$ as $$\left(\forall m\in\mathbb N \;\;\forall b_1,\ldots,b_m\in\mathbb R^+ \prod_{j=1}^m b_j =1\right)\implies \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \geq n,$$ with the variables $n$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ free.

P.P.S. Unlike parentheses, a colon is unable to indicate the scope of quantifiers.

Comment: Is $ \forall n\in\mathbb N \;\;\forall a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb R^+ $ a valid quantification? since the number of quantifiers depend on one of its quantifiers

Comment: @hazelnut_116 How do you mean by "the number of quantifiers depend on one of its quantifiers"?  But yes, that's just an abbreviation of the quantification portion of your Attempt 1; it still contains $(n+1)$ quantifiers. (Incidentally, when consolidating adjacent quantifiers *of the same type*, their order doesn't matter.) Another example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4223517/21813).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2407834/865056
In the 5-th comment by Maxime Ramzi, hey says  " But @Noah, even in set theory, ∃k,∃v1,...,∃vk is not valid quantification ... ".   So I was thinking that the number of quantifiers that depend on one of the quantified variable is illegal , I'm not familiar with ZFC theory ( I'm only familiar with naive set theory ), but maybe such a quantification is legal when we're speaking in the language of ZFC set theory?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 In all your three attempts, and in the lemma that you specified, (and in my suggested translation), the count of the variable $a_j$ (i.e. what you call "the number of quantifiers") is a function of (i.e. ***does*** depend on) $n;$ how else would you have it? p.s. I expanded my answer.

Comment: You are right, I don't see any other way that would be significantly different to the one in your attempt, I'm overthinking this, thanks!